# Checking Visual Studio files for code comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm looking for a Visual Studio 2008 add-in or macro that will examine all of the .cs files and report back on "code comment coverage".  Our company's standard is that all C# classes, methods, and properties are code commented.  I've got a large solution, and going through the files by hand wastes a lot of time.  If I had a report that told me exactly which files have code comments and which ones don't, I could examine just those files.

I don't mind writing some code to accomplish this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Is there an add-in or macro that does this?  Failing that, is there a way to use reflection or the System.CodeDom namespace to check a class for code comments?  If I could just get my classes loaded into an object model, I could probably get the rest of the way there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) checks for XML documentation on classes and class members.

Answer (score 5):

Just enable the [XML documentation](http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html) output in the project build settings, then enable "all warnings as errors". You will now get errors for any undocumented classes and members that are not private or internal.

The [Ghost Doc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) extension for Visual Studio is great to reduce typing effort here, and it's free.

[Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB) is the easiest way to channel all that documentation effort into nice looking HTML, CHM or HxS files.

One last cool thing: it's possible to [reference code regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301365/automatically-unit-test-example-code/604525#604525) that will be included as examples in your documentation . Recycle those unit tests as documentation and make sure the samples are correct: two birds with one stone! :-)