# Testing sample code in python modules

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm in the process of writing a python module that includes some samples. These samples aren't unit-tests, and they are too long and complex to be doctests. I'm interested in best practices for automatically checking that these samples run.

My current project layout is pretty standard, except that there is an extra top level makefile that has build, install, unittest, coverage and profile targets, that delegate responsibility to setup.py and nose as required.

```
projectname/
    Makefile
    README
    setup.py
    samples/
        foo-sample
        foobar-sample
    projectname/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
    tests/
        test-foo.py
        test-bar.py
```

I've considered adding a sampletest module, or adding `nose.tools.istest` decorators to the entry-point functions of the samples, but for a small number of samples, these solutions sound a bit ugly.

This question is similar to [Automatically Unit Test Example Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301365/automatically-unit-test-example-code), but I assume python best practices will differ from C#

Comment: Is it ideal to have file 'projectname' under 'projectname?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, I just use `unittest` for testing my examples and functional tests. It isn't unit testing, but a lot of what I do with the unittest module isn't. To quote Knuth, "A computer doesn’t mind if its programs are put to purposes that don’t match their names."

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  run_tests()
```

in the module code? This way, it will only run if the module is called as a stand-alone progran, not when it's `import`ed into other code.

Comment: The problem is that some of the modules have multiple samples, and that code in those samples isn't related to the code in the module